# IE11 / Edge : css hover behavirour on resizing / moving elements

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, hover

I have a IE-specific problem with a menu on my site.

When the user hovers on a menu object, a sub-menu opens with the related choices.
This is made with a small div getting bigger (max-height change) with a :hover css rule.

I force-close the menu by hiding it momentarily (this makes chrome & firefox properly give up the :hover behaviour).

**Problem:**
On IE : as long as the mouse did not move, the :hover is still active, so the menu stays open.

The problem is the same on moving elements :

If I hover a moving div, the css behavior works, but if I stop moving my mouse and the div is moved by a script, it keeps the hover behavior altought its not under the mouse anymore.

**Question :**
How can I force IE to reset/recheck its hover behavior ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. Without it, there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: I cannot provide a tailored, simplified exemple of the problem in a reasonable time as the site's scripts are too large for that and I dont know where the problem comes from - nor if it even comes from something specific in the source.

Also I would rather not give the url in public as Id rather not have my client's enterprise name accidentally referred in "buggy site" context.

I can provide the url via private message tough, if you have an iPhone and would be interested in trying to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you cannot bring the problem down into a small enough chunk to be analyzed on Stack Overflow then I'm afraid you're on your own.